# How to update a jQuery object containing a list of elements after moving an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

There's a list of elements, let's say some images:

```
<img src="" alt="">
<img src="" alt="">
<img src="" alt="">
```

I select them and store the result in a variable:

```
var elements = $('img');
```

Now I want to bring the last image to the first position. It works fine like this:

```
elements.first().before(elements.last());
```

After that the object `elements` naturally still holds the values in the order they where before. I can update this by querying again after the shift:

```
elements = $('img');
```

But it seems inefficient to run another query when I already have all the elements together. Also, as it's not an array this won't work:

```
elements.unshift(elements.pop());
```

What's the best way to update the object list in such a case?

Comment: `$('img').toArray()` will return array of matched elements.

Comment: `var elements = $('img').get();` would make it an array of DOM elements.

Comment: The comments are telling you how to get an array without realizing that you are trying to _mutate the collection_.

Comment: Why do you consider it inefficient to reassign the `elements` var? 1 line of code accomplishes exactly what you want.

Comment: @inorganik I thought: A new query takes a certain amount of time - the selector is slightly more complicated and there are more elements than in the example. So if I already have them selected before I think it should take less time to simply shift the list in the jQuery object than running the query again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fake it!

```
[].unshift.call(elements, [].pop.call(elements))
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q95F5/)

---

Caveat: I doubt this is faster than re-executing the query.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this nice answer. I think I stick to re-querying again this time, as other people working on the project might get confused seeing this line of code. *Hehe* :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on here.

You have a set of elements in the DOM, and a variable holding a DOM fragment of references to those elements.

The jQuery `first()` and `last()` functions are moving the elements in the DOM, but they don't know anything about the variable.

From a code simplicity point of view, your suggested code is the most readable, and should be fine unless you are calling it a lot.

```
elements = $('img');
```

Otherwise, turn the variable into an array:

```
var elementsarray = [];
elements.each(function(i) { elementsarray[] = this; });
```

Comment: +1 For "*From a code simplicity point of view, your suggested code is the most readable[…]*. That's what I figured too in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
 <img src="" alt="">
 <img src="" alt="">
 <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

---

```
$('.container img:last-child').prependTo('.container'); //would work

$('img:last', elements).prependTo(elements); 
// i think this will also work if you need to cache it
```